# Coding and Decoding

Tags: cipher, pattern

In a certain code language:

- 'Great Ghost goes Germany' is written as FOTF4T
- 'round she goes crazy' is written as ZEHR
- 'Canada can create ' is written as CAK3X
- 'Just not good enough' is written as UOOJ

**What is the logic behind this code?** Why are these phrases encoded in this way?

Comment: well for starts 2nd and 4th statement contains letter from each word

Comment: and 1st and 3rd statements denote the no of repetitions of first character of each word in code

Comment: Which book? What's it called? Please cite your source.

Comment: Source is Grade app , I am practising for exams ok,Now explain the coding and decoding please,I am sking help from you,I am new to puzzle stackexchange, why are you asking these many questions friends

Comment: why they are devoting my question,explain please

Comment: The main problem with this question is that is in broken English and not using correct terms and that you're not really responding to the questions asked. For example the title is "Coding and Decoding" which suggests it is some cypher for encoding stuff and decoding stuff. However it is seems that this is only for one way encoding with no possible way to get the original back with only the result. So you're not really asking people to decode something but you're asking what function is applied to the sentence to get the resulting code.

Comment: @elavarasan don't panic, this happens to all newbies here. Its part of learning process. Your question made it look like that you were asking for some online ongoing contest so you got many raised brows there :) Have fun learning and don't let this discourage you.

Comment: Now only I have some restful peace in my heart,Thank you for giving wonderful message to me @Sikorski

Comment: I've deleted a lot of the comments here. In the future, to everyone who commented here, please avoid dogpiling new users. I get that everyone was trying to be helpful, and that's great, honestly, but too many people can be too much for a new user to face.

Comment: @Learninguser for the first and third lines, the letters before the numbers are just the sum of the vowels present in each word. For ex; Canada has 3 a's so 1+1+1=3, which is the position of the letter C. Similarly in Germany, we have 5+1=6=F.Also, I would like if you could post these questions in PG also.It would be of great help to a lot of us who are regularly present there. And this question was also solved today by one of the members of PG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what this thing is, but here's what I have found out:

> For the 4th, go backwards starting from the $n$th letter of the $n$th word. For the 2nd, go forwards using the same algorithm.

As @Elias points out:

> In 1st and 3rd words, the last letter(i.e. letter after the number) is Atbash for the common first letter. (As T is Atbash for G and X is atbash for C). I have no idea about the 1st and the 3rd but those numbers indicate the no.of words containing the first letter common to the sentences +1.(For example 4= 3 words having C as the 1st letter +1)

Comment: The last letter of 1st and 3rd is an atbash for the common first letters.

Comment: Ah, Yes! That makes much more sense.

Comment: Hi @elias atbash for the common first letters means